# sphinx is returning stale results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Environment:

Memcached, Rails 2.2.2 + cache_money, Sphinx + thinking sphinx

The following yields stale results:
- add a record; mysql contains the correct data
- the record is probably cached in memory at this point
- re-index sphinx
- sphinx returns the proper result with the correct data
- edit the record
- the cache is invalidated properly, mysql contains the correct, updated data
- re-index sphinx again
- sphinx is now stale

Re-indexing sphinx, clearing memcached, and/or editing the questionable records all have no effect. Disabling the cache layer all together (cache_money plus memcached) also has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your delta query just get new, unindexed rows from your table(s), or is it grabbing every row with a modified time greater than a specified value?

Comment: the former; weird thing is the problem is no longer a problem... just cleared up.

Comment: It sounds like the entire table(s) was reindexed. If your delta query is only grabbing new rows, changes in UPDATEd rows won't be reflected in the full-text index.